# Showing that $\int^{t}_{0}B^{2}_{s}dB_{s}=\frac{1}{3}B^{3}_{t} - \int^{t}_{0}B_{s}ds$, without Ito formula

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to prove the following via the direct definition of Ito integrals (i.e. without the use of the Ito formula).

> $$ \int^{t}_{0}B^{2}_{s}dB_{s}=\frac{1}{3}B^{3}_{t} - \int^{t}_{0}B_{s}ds$$

**Progress so far**

> So Using the Definition of the Ito integral we can write 
>   $$\int^{t}_{0}B^{2}_{S}dB_{s}=\lim_\limits{\Delta t_{j} \ \to 0}\sum_\limits{j}B^{2}_{j}\Delta B_{j}$$ 
>   Where $\Delta B_{j}=[B_{j+1}-B_{j}]. $
>
> From here i then started by trying to calculate $\Delta(B^{3}_{j})$ which i got
>
> $$ \Delta(B^{3}_{j}) = B^{3}_{j+1}-B^{3}_{j} = (B_{j+1}-B_{j})^{3}+3B_{j}B_{j+1}\Delta B_{j}$$

However this doesn't really get the desired result i'm not sure how to proceed i assume i have calculated $\Delta (B^{3}_{j})$ incorrectly?